# sorting varchar column as date

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar column with date as MM-yyyy format.

```
    10-2018
    11-2018
    12-2017
```

I want to sort it so that the result is

```
    12-2017
    10-2018
    11-2018
```

Comment: Then store your dates as what they are, a `date`. A `varchar` and `date` have very different ordering. With a `varchar` the expression `'9' > '100'` is true, however, with an `int`, it would be false. The same applies here `'11-2018' < '12-2017'`. Change your data to a`date` (in your table preferably), and then it won't be a problem.

Comment: I will just leave this here for you to read. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: @SeanLange it seems bad data choices are the subject of the day. I think this is the 4th question I've seen with this type of problem in half the hours.

Comment: @Larnu indeed!!!

Comment: sorry for incorrect information, I have queried in above mentioned format but want it displayed in order. The column is not of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you append a day value, then use the `CONVERT` function with a 103 style code, it will allow the dates to be sorted as dates.

```
....
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,'01-'+ DateAsStringColumn ,103);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention in a comment:

> sorry for incorrect information, I have queried in above mentioned format but want it displayed in order. The column is not of that type.

That's easy then: Just use the original columns in your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT someExpressionThatYieldsMMandYYYY
  FROM ...
 ORDER BY theRealUnderlyingDatetimeField
```

or

```
SELECT someExpressionThatYieldsMMandYYYY
  FROM ...
 ORDER BY theRealUnderlyingYearField, theRealUnderlyingMonthField
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your column name is ColumnA and your table name is TableA:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY SUBSTRING(ColumnA ,4,4),ColumnA
```